# how do I display booked appointment on calendar? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've been following Dakota Lee Martinez Appointment project to try and adapt it to my project (my project is a booking system that books appointments for customers. I've been trying to get my appointments to show up on the calendar like it does with his, however I'm slightly confused as to how I should. I've tried many times but keep getting errors.

(Using gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0" to display the calendar)

Error:

```
NoMethodError in AppointmentsController#index

undefined method `upcoming_appointments' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Sites/booking_saloniser - Calendar

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

Dakota page: https://medium.com/@dakotaleemartinez/rails-appointments-project-4a16eaf1f7ca

Dakota Repo: https://github.com/DakotaLMartinez/rails-appointments

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <h1>New Appointment</h1>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { appointment: @appointment, client: @client } %>
 </div>  
</div>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Appointments <%= link_to "+ New", new_appointment_path %></h1>

<%= add_weekly_calendar(@appointments) %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/errors", locals: { object: appointment } %>
<%= form_for appointment do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <p>
      <%= label_tag "appointment[appointment_time][date]", "Date" %>
      <%= text_field_tag "appointment[appointment_time][date]", appointment_date(appointment), class: "datepicker" %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <p id="time">
      <%= label_tag "appointment[appointment_time][hour]", "Time" %>
      <%= hour_selector("appointment[appointment_time][hour]", appointment) %> : 
      <%= min_selector("appointment[appointment_time][min]", appointment) %> 
    </p>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <p>
     <%= f.label :duration %> 
     <%= duration_hour_field("appointment[duration][hour]", appointment) %>
     <%= duration_minute_field("appointment[duration][min]", appointment) %>
   </p>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <p>
     <%= f.label :price %> 
     <%= f.number_field :price, step: 0.25, value: float_two_decimals(appointment.price) %>
   </p>  
 </div>
 <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

**appointment.rb**

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :client
accepts_nested_attributes_for :client

def start_time
  self.appointment_time
end

def end_time
  appointment_time + duration.seconds
end

def client_name 
  client.name
end

## Form Parsing methods

def client_attributes=(atts)
  if atts[:name] != ""
    self.client = self.user.clients.find_or_create_by(atts)   
  end
end

def appointment_time=(time)
  if time.is_a?(Hash)
    self[:appointment_time] = parse_datetime(time) 
  else
    self[:appointment_time] = time
  end
end

def parse_date(string)
  array = string.split("/")
  first_item = array.pop
  array.unshift(first_item).join("-")
end

def parse_datetime(hash)
  if hash["date"].match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)
    Time.zone.parse("#{parse_date(hash["date"])} #{hash["hour"]}:#{hash["min"]}")
  end
end

def duration=(duration) 
  if duration.is_a?(Hash)
    self[:duration] = parse_duration(duration)
  else 
    self[:duration] = duration
  end
end

def parse_duration(hash)
  hash["hour"].to_i + hash["min"].to_i
end
end
```

**appointments_controller.rb**

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_appointment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# GET /appointments
# GET /appointments.json
def index
  @upcoming_appointments = current_user.upcoming_appointments
end

# GET /appointments/1
# GET /appointments/1.json
def show

end

# GET /appointments/new
def new
  @appointments = current_user.appointments.select { |a| a.persisted? }
  @appointment = current_user.appointments.build
end

# GET /appointments/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /appointments
# POST /appointments.json
def create
  @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @appointment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @appointment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /appointments/1
# PATCH/PUT /appointments/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @appointment }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /appointments/1
# DELETE /appointments/1.json
def destroy
  @appointment.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to appointments_url, notice: 'Appointment was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_appointment
  @appointment = current_user.appointments.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @appointment.nil? 
    flash[:error] = "Appointment not found."
    redirect_to appointments_path
  end
end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def appointment_params
    params.require(:appointment).permit(:appointment_time, :duration, :price, :user_id, :client_id)
  end
```

end

Is there any chance someone could help me how I could do what Dakota has done on his project? I've tried searching different gems etc to help me with this doing this but I like what Dakota has done.

Comment: 'Keep getting errors', and what are those errors? You will have to be a lot more focused if you want to get answers.

Comment: Just updated the post (added error and updated controller).

Comment: Ok, your `current_user` is `nil` for some reason.

Comment: So I've added `before_filter :authenticate_user! `, I'm guessing its no longer nil?

Comment: It is not nil if you log in. Don't you know if you are logging in?